# jQuery Check if a Radio Button is Selected or not

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, checked

I have a table as follows and with radio buttons to select the Table Row.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <label class="radio">
                      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" data-toggle="radio">
                    </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center"><img class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="exaple-image" src="images/covers/02.jpg"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="selected-row">
                  <td>
                    <label class="radio">
                      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" data-toggle="radio" checked>
                    </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center"><img class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="exaple-image" src="images/covers/01.jpg"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <label class="radio">
                      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" data-toggle="radio">
                    </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center"><img class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="exaple-image" src="images/covers/03.jpg"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <label class="radio">
                      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" data-toggle="radio">
                    </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center"><img class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="exaple-image" src="images/covers/04.jpg"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <label class="radio">
                      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" data-toggle="radio">
                    </label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center"><img class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="exaple-image" src="images/covers/05.jpg"></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Now when i select a a Radio Button i wanna highlight that row and remove highlight from the other rows.

```
// Table: Add class row selected
$('.table tbody :radio').on('check uncheck toggle', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        check = $this.prop('checked'),
        toggle = e.type == 'toggle',
        checkboxes = $('.table tbody :radio'),
        checkAll = checkboxes.length == checkboxes.filter(':checked').length

        $this.closest('tr')[check ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('selected-row');
    if (toggle) $this.closest('.table').find('.toggle-all :radio').checkbox(checkAll ? 'check' : 'uncheck');
});
```

**Error:**

> It highlights the selected row but doesnt remove hightlight from
>   previously selected row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Table: Add class row selected
$('.table tbody :radio').change(function() {
    $('.table tbody :radio:checked').closest('tr').addClass('selected-row');
    $('.table tbody :radio:not(:checked)').closest('tr').removeClass('selected-row');
});
```

Comment: i think your answer is better, just to get rid of all of the "parent()" chaining ".closest()" will be good

Answer (score 1):

Using this can also work.

```
$('.table tbody :radio').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("selected-row");
    $(".table tbody :radio").not(this).closest("tr").removeClass("selected-row")
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydast/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Throwing my two-cents out on the table.

You can add a class to the closest tr (which from your example would be the radio buttons parent) and then remove classes from the closest tr siblings.

```
$('.table').on('change', ':radio', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected-row').siblings('tr').removeClass('selected-row'); 
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wYM8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$('#element').click(function() {
  if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
  });
```

Comment: i am already able to add the css class. its not removing the previously selected row if i change the selection